# Lambda + stream to fetch List<A> to A Single List

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I have a class

```
class TestA {
            private List<A> listA;

      //Getters and Setters
}
```

and another class

```
class A{
       int id;
}
```

Now if want to collect all A into a List like below code

```
List<TestA> someList ; //Containing TestA
List<A> completeList = new LinkedList<A>();
for(TestA test:someList) {
  if(test.getListA() != null) {
    completeList.addAll(listA);
  }
}
```

How can I get ***completeList*** using Lambda + Stream . Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: @Holger Thanks . However , there could some cases where  **listA** is null . So if I re-write your code to as below , will it work ?

    List<A> completeList = someList.stream().**filter( c -> !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(c.getListA())**.flatMap(test -> test.getListA().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Generally, don’t use these awful `CollectionUtils`. If you want to test for `null`, test for `null`, if you want to test for an empty `Collection`, use `isEmpty()`. Make it explicit, what you are doing instead of calling these methods mixing these things. And avoid doing things twice (i.e. `getListA()`). Map to the result of `getListA`, filter it, do the next processing step… And prefer using non-`null` collections in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should look something like this...

```
  someList.stream()
     .map(TestA::getListA)
     .filter(testA -> testA != null && !testA.isEmpty())
     .flatMap(List::stream)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The test for `!testA.isEmpty()` is not needed. So `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can formulate it (Eugene's approach, that is) more declaratively:

```
someList.stream()
    .flatMap(testA -> Optional.ofNullable(testA.getListA()).getOrElse(new ArrayList<>()).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```